# Problema en la conexión a base de datos mysql

Tags: java, base-de-datos

La cuestión es la siguiente:

1. Tengo el siguiente código para crear una conexión con una BD que se llama `bd_alumnos` en MySql:

   ```
   public class Conexion {
   private static Conexion instancia=null;
   private static Connection conn;

   private Conexion()
   {
       String host="127.0.0.1:3306";
       String user="root";
       String pass="xxxx";
       String dtbs="bd_alumnos";

       try
       {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //Inicializar el driver
          String newConnectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+dtbs
                       + "?" +"user=" + user + "&password=" + pass;
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(newConnectionURL);
       }catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }    
   }

   public static Conexion getInstancia()
   {
       if(instancia==null) instancia=new Conexion();
       return instancia;
   }
   ```
2. Estoy usando el patrón de programación Singleton.
3. Me da el siguiente error:

> run: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Unknown database 'bd_alumnos'     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2412)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2445)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2230)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:813)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)  at
>   Conexion.Conexion.(Conexion.java:31)    at
>   Conexion.Conexion.getInstancia(Conexion.java:40)  at
>   bdalumnos.BDAlumnos.main(BDAlumnos.java:18) BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total
>   time: 1 second)

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: la base se llama bd_alumnos? igual el error es que no la reconoce.. desde donde estas ejecutando?? se ven las 2 maquinas?

Comment: estás seguro de que esa bd existe?

Comment: 1 El usuario tiene permisos para ver dicha base. 2 la base tiene el nombre exacto `bd_alumnos`, puedes validarlo en el mysqlworkbench

Comment: pon estas lineas en el catch:  **System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());**, a ver si pueden dar algo mas de informacion (sabiendo el errorCode). Por otra parte, en el metodo getInstancia() the falta el **this** para asignar la instancia por primera vez, y para cojerla siempre.

Answer (score 1):

La forma en que te conectas es extraña, sobre todo esta línea:

```
   String newConnectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+dtbs
                + "?" +"user=" + user + "&password=" + pass;
```

Esto también me parece algo extraño:

```
if(instancia==null) instancia=new Conexion();
```

Haciendo la conexión de esta manera debería funcionar:

```
public class Conexion {
private static Conexion instancia=null;
private static Connection conn;

private Conexion()
{
    String host="127.0.0.1:3306";
    String user="root";
    String pass="xxxx";
    String dtbs="bd_alumnos";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String connection = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+dtbs;

    try
    {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, user, pass);

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}

    public static Conexion getInstancia()
    {
        if(instancia==null) instancia=new Conexion();
        return instancia;
    }
```

[Aquí tienes otros ejemplos](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/MySQL.htm) de conexión con el driver de MySQL.

Como ya se ha dicho en comentarios, verifica que la BD existe y que se llama así realmente y que la misma está *escuchando* en el puerto `3306`.